# Anant (Infinite) - Is this Bhagwan Shiv Ji's name or Bhagwan Vishnu Ji's name?

Tags: vedas, shiva, vishnu, reference-request, name

Given that it is said 'Hari Anant Hari Katha Anantha...', and at other places, how Mahadev is Mahakaal i.e. 'beyond time' kind of infinity, and also in the story where Shiv Ji took form of infinite lingam, it causes confusion which God Ji can be called 'Anant'? I guess both, Mahadev and Vishu Ji both.  Any supporting references in the Veds or Purans?

Comment: None....Anant means endless..... thats it.. its a word or term not a name!!

Comment: Ananta means endless, is one of the properties of Brahman.

Answer (score 2):

*Shiv and shri hari both are infinite*
but name anant is of multi headed snake on which shri hari rests

Bhagavad Gita: Chapter 10, Verse 29

***अनन्तश्चास्मि नागानां*** वरुणो यादसामहम् |

पितृणामर्यमा चास्मि यम: संयमतामहम् || 29||

***Amongst the snakes I am Anant***; amongst aquatics I am Varun. Amongst the departed ancestors I am Aryama; amongst dispensers of law I am Yamraj, the lord of death.

Answer (score 1):

Ananta is a name of Lord Vishnu -

> "**He is called Ananta from his eternity**, and Govinda from his
> knowledge of speech of every kind."

- Sanatsujata Parva, Mahabharata.

> "**The deities and the Asuras have never been able to ascertain my
> beginning, my middle, or my end.** It is for this reason that I am sung
> as Anadi, Amadhya and **Ananta**".

- Moksha Dharma Parva, Mahabharata.

Supreme Lord Vishnu is called Ananta because the people does not know his orgin or end -

> You are higher than the highest.
> **People neither know your end nor your origin nor who you are in reality."**

- Yuddha kanda, Valmiki Ramayana.

Answer (score 0):

You can find almost all names in every deities Sahastra Namas or Gitas, etc. But.:

Siva-Rahasya Mahetihasa, 1st Amsha, Chapter 3.:

> Mahadeva alone is known by the names of Brahma, Vishnu, Indra, Mitra, etc. by the gods. **He alone is known thus with names and forms due to maayaa by people.**

Skanda-Māhapurāṇa, 4.66.107-109.:

> He (Shiva) is the omniscient one to be known only through the Vedas. The entire universe is his progeny. He is one whom no one has known even at the outset. It is he who is (reputed to be) one who should be known through the Vedas. He alone is the omniscient one who always has remained misunderstood and unknowable. **Not even a single name of his can be fully comprehended by any man.
> It is certain, he bears all the names of everyone as his names.** He belongs to all climes and regions. He is bestower of all supernatural powers on all.

MBH H.P. 3.88.:

> **Whatever names you have oh Govinda, they are my (Maheshwara's) names only without doubt.**

As for the Ananta name.:

Kaivalya Upanishad.:

> 6-7. At the center of the lotus of the heart, meditating upon that which is pure, without passion, clear, without sorrow, unthinkable, unmanifest, **infinite (ananta) in form,** auspicious (shiva), peaceful (shanta), eternal (amrita) and the cause of Brahma. **Without a beginning, middle or an end,** who is one, all pervading, of blissful consciousness, without form, wonderful, seated with the goddess Uma, the Supreme Lord, the ruler, bearing three eyes, with a blue neck, ever peaceful - by meditating upon Him the sages attain the source of all creation, the witness of all and that which is beyond all darkness.

MBH 12:232:41-42.:

> “I (Vyasa) have, before this, spoken to thee of **Kala** which is **without beginning and without end,** and which ordains this variety in the universe. It is that Kala which creates and swallows up all creatures. All the innumerable creatures that exist subject to pairs of opposites and according to their respective natures, have Kala for their refuge. It is Kala that assumes those shapes and it is Kala that upholds them.

As for who is this Kāla.?

Taittiriya Aranyaka 10.18.1.:

> “Salutation to Vamadeva. Salutation to Jyestha (the Eldest, existing before creation). Salutation to Srestha (the most worthy and excellent). **Salutation to Rudra. Salutation to Kala. Salutation to Kalavikarana (He who causes changes in the evolution of the universe beginning with Prakriti)”.**

Ṣvētāṣvatāra Upaniṣad 6:16.:

> “He (i.e., Rudra) makes all, he knows all, the self-caused, the knower, **the time of time (destroyer of time),** who assumes qualities and knows everything, the master of nature and of man, the lord of the three qualities (guna), the cause of the bondage, the existence, and the liberation of the world”
> Even,

MBH 1:2:350.:

> “In this, both Balarama and Kesava (Krishna) after causing the extermination of their race, their hour having come, **themselves did not rise superior to the sway of all-destroying Kala”.**

Sri Shiva Gita 6.35 of Padma Purana U.K.:

> **Because Brahma and Vishnu failed to locate my beginning and end, I am called to be infinite (ananta).**

I hope this clarifies all your queries. Prd..